# NavigationDrawer blocks other button on the activity

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, button, navigation-drawer

I'm working on the UI of my app and I'm facing a problem when I implement the Navigation Drawer. As you can see [here](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/480224Capture.jpg), I have some buttons to manage my Media Player, these are not responding to my clicks when I implement the Navigation Drawer (working fine without Navigation Drawer).

I think the problem is coming from my XML file because there are no changing when I delete the implementation in Java.

Here are my XML sheets :

**main_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.ilan.myapplication.fragments.FragmentHome" >
    </fragment>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Buffering"
        android:id="@+id/tV_Buffering"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/player_controls"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I put the Navigation Drawer in the end to have it to cover the all activity.

**navigation_drawer_main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**player_controls.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_play_pause"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tV_Buffering"
            android:background="@drawable/bouton_play"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:id="@+id/button_stop"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_play_pause"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Well, if anyone has any idea from where this come from it would be awesome, thanks !

Comment: Instead of including player_controls as part of main_activity implement them as part of fragment

Comment: @VyprNoch I don't understand how this would be different ? I mean in my problem, this won't affect anything isn't it ? Because otherwise it would imply that we are forced to use only fragments when we use a Navigation Drawer, in my case the player will always be part of the activity.

Comment: maybe because the "navigation_drawer_main_layout" is above "player_controls" so it get click/touch events. try to change android:layout_width="match_parent" to android:layout_width="xx dp"   in "<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" (make sure that **xx** is less than half of your screen, to not hide the "play button")

Comment: Arf, no effects, I tried in <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" this not get the situation any better and also directly in the <include but here I get an Exception : "IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY."

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have same issue but couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first child with width and height of match_parent and no layout_gravity. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a fixed width. Check out the documentation of google regarding to DrawerLayout : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html.

Your primary content should put inside DrawerLayout instead of including the DrawerLayout inside your RelativeLayout.

For your case, you could try to implement it this way instead:
**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MyActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragments"
            class="com.example.ilan.myapplication.fragments.FragmentHome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </fragment>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tV_Buffering"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Buffering"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/player_controls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```